# react-navigation add custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I add my own header component so I can add an image in the nav?

I setup my header like this, I can set components for the right and left, but how do I add a centred image to my nav?

```
const headerStyle = {
  paddingHorizontal: theme.metrics.mainPadding,
  paddingTop: 2,
  paddingBottom: 2,
  backgroundColor: theme.colors.purple,
  justifyContent: 'center',
};

const headerTitleStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  alignItems: 'center',
  ...theme.fontStyles.appBarTitle,
};

const headerRight = <Text>logo here</Text>;
const headerLeft = <Text>text here</Text>;

export default {
  title,
  headerStyle,
  headerTitleStyle,
  headerRight,
  headerLeft,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set header visibility in every component to hide header.

```
static navigationOptions = {
 header: {
  visible: false,
 }
};
```

React-Navigation has changed the api for hiding the header from [v1.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9). Use `header: null` instead.

```
static navigationOptions = {
 header: null
};
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I add a header once I've hidden the default one?

Comment: use `native-base` , you can add your code between `<Header> ...</Header>` element.